# How to call a function more then once?

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, filter

How would I go about calling a function multiple times in different parts of my code. Currently I am just replicating the function and giving all of the variables a different name and calling that separate variable. I will add an example below. The method works but there is no way its efficient. What would be the better way to do it? Thank you for the help and I apologize for the silly question.

**JS**

```
              // Variable 1
          
          const filterButtons = document.querySelector("#filter-btns").children;
          const items = document.querySelector(".blog__content").children;
        
          for(let i =0; i < filterButtons.length; i++) {
            filterButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
              for (let j =0; j < filterButtons.length; j++) {
                filterButtons[j].classList.remove("active2")
              }
              this.classList.add("active2");
              const target = this.getAttribute("data-target")
        
              for (let k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
                items[k].style.display = "none";
                if (target == items[k].getAttribute("data-id")) {
                  items[k].style.display = "block";
                }
                if (target == "all") {
                  items[k].style.display = "block";
                }
              }
            })
          }



          // Variable 2
          
          const filterButtons2 = document.querySelector("#filter-btns2").children;
          const items2 = document.querySelector(".blog__content").children;
        
          for(let i =0; i < filterButtons2.length; i++) {
            filterButtons2[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
              for (let j =0; j < filterButtons2.length; j++) {
                filterButtons2[j].classList.remove("active2")
              }
              this.classList.add("active2");
              const target = this.getAttribute("data-target")
        
              for (let k = 0; k < items2.length; k++) {
                items2[k].style.display = "none";
                if (target == items2[k].getAttribute("data-id")) {
                  items2[k].style.display = "block";
                }
                if (target == "all") {
                  items2[k].style.display = "block";
                }
              }
            })
          }
```

**HTML**

```
               <div id="filter-btns"> 
                    <a data-target="corn">
                     

                        <span>Corn</span>

                </a>
               </div>






              <div id="filter-btns2"> 
                    <a data-target="chicken">

                        <span>Chicken</span>
                </a>
                </div>
```

Comment: to call *a function* twice, you'd first create a function to call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a function to call if you want to call it twice

```
function fn(query) {
    const filterButtons = document.querySelector(query).children;
    const items = document.querySelector(".blog__content").children;

    for (let i = 0; i < filterButtons.length; i++) {
        filterButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            for (let j = 0; j < filterButtons.length; j++) {
                filterButtons[j].classList.remove("active2");
            }
            this.classList.add("active2");
            const target = this.getAttribute("data-target");

            for (let k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
                items[k].style.display = "none";
                if (target == items[k].getAttribute("data-id")) {
                    items[k].style.display = "block";
                }
                if (target == "all") {
                    items[k].style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can call it twice

```
fn('#filter-btns');
fn('#filter-btns2');
```